# Adding Activity Indicator after Clicking "LOGIN"?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I would like to add an Activity Indicator for my Login VC so that users will see that spinner thing once they click the "login" button. I have done multiple attempts and failed. Even if I put in codes for hiding the activity indicator, it just keeps animating even before clicking the "login" button. I deleted those codes, and have my original codes below (without activity indicator).

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "background")
        imageView.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)
    }

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    //Login Action
    @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" {
            //Alert to tell the user that there was an error because they didn't fill anything in the textfields because they didn't fill anything in

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    //Print into the console if successfully logged in
                    print("You have successfully logged in")

                    //Go to the HomeViewController if the login is sucessful
                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so I know the first step is probably dragging the activity indicator to the VC in Storyboard, but what's next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     In your storyboard, you can find  checkbox.
```

1. startsAnimating
2. HidesWhenStops(check this in your storyboard.)

   ```
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicator!

    @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    if self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" {
       //Alert to tell the user that there was an error because they didn't fill anything in the textfields because they didn't fill anything in

         let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
       let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
       alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

       self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   } else {
       Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
           if error == nil {
               //Print into the console if successfully logged in
               print("You have successfully logged in")
               activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
               //Go to the HomeViewController if the login is sucessful
               let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
               self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
           } else {
               //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
               let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

               let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
               alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

               self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a **IBOutlet of dragged UIActivityIndicator**. Then in **`viewDidLoad`func hide this UIActivityIndicator with it's IBOutlet**. When you click on Login Button, then unhide this activityIndicator and hide again, once receive response from login.

Answer (score 3):

Create an IBOUtlet of your activity indicator from Storyboard to your Viewcontroller - [image: Creating Outlet]

You can then in your ViewDidLoad or your storyboard set the below property

```
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;
```

And when you want to start it, call

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating();
```

And to stop it from animating -

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
```

Answer (score 3):

The same way you created your IBOutlets of `UITextField`, create one with your `UIActivityIndicator`. Make sure your indicator's `hidesWhenStopped` is set to true in the storyboard.

Then animate it before calling your signin method, and stop it on the completion handler

```
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicator!
//...
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in {
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
//...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create UIActivityIndicatorView in your class programmatically & customize it in viewDidLoad

```
 var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)

  // Add below code in viewDidLoad

 self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
 self.activityIndicator.center = view.center
 self.view.addSubView(self.activityIndicator)
```

Now do start & stop animating whereever you need

```
 //Login Action
    @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        if self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" {

            //Alert to tell the user that there was an error because they didn't fill anything in the textfields because they didn't fill anything in

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                if error == nil {

                    //Print into the console if successfully logged in
                    print("You have successfully logged in")

                    //Go to the HomeViewController if the login is sucessful
                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {

                    //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative Approach. Adding the `UIActivityViewController` programatically:

1. In the `LoginViewController` class add

   let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
2. In the `viewDidLoad()` add the following

   myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
               myActivityIndicator.center = view.center
               view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)
3. In `@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject)` in the else part 
   add

   activityIndicator.startAnimating()
       Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in {
       activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

Answer (score 1):

I have written a class to use progress hud properly. You just need to drag and drop the class to your project...
https://github.com/emraz/ERProgressHud

For showing progress hud write ..

```
ERProgressHud.show()
```

For hiding progress hud write ..

```
ERProgressHud.hide()
```

In your code ..

//Login Action

@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

```
if self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" {

    //Alert to tell the user that there was an error because they didn't fill anything in the textfields because they didn't fill anything in
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return

}
else {

    ERProgressHud.show()

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

        ERProgressHud.hide()
        if error == nil {

            //Print into the console if successfully logged in
            print("You have successfully logged in")

            //Go to the HomeViewController if the login is sucessful
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
}
```